# how generate and substitute files with sed

Tags: sed, variable-substitution

I need to change the seed's value, the output (`HA.xyz`) and the namefile to generate 100 different files.

```
# MSA: H2O
seed 129472
tolerance 1.0
filetype xyz
output HA.xyz

Structure H2O.xyz
 number
 inside cube
end structure

Structure .xyz
 number
 inside cube
end structure
```

Comment: Where is the variable namefile? Where is your program, and what is your exact question? Please read the [tour], we are not a script-writing service.

Comment: Where do you keep the 100 names and the seed values? And what does this have to do with `make`?

Comment: i have a file with thousands of  random numbers

Comment: The namefile is the same as the seed

Comment: What is the format of that file? Seed, followed by a filename, with a space inbetween?

Comment: @EduardoMtz Once more, **please read the [tour]**, so you start to understand how this site works. And then edit your post and make it an acceptable question, instead of hiding information in comments. As it is your post will most likely be closed, and reopening a closed post is always more difficult than spending the time up-front to make it acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r seed name; do
    sed -e "s/^seed.*/seed $seed/" \
        -e "s/^output.*/output $name/" template.txt >"${name%.*}-$seed.conf"
done <file.in
```

This will read a file called `file.in`.  The format of that file should be

```
00000 filename.ext
```

(seed value in the first column, a space, and a filename)

The `sed` command will take the template from `template.txt`, a file formatted as in the question and generate new files.

The new files will have names like `filename-00000.conf` (using the filename, without filename extension, and seed from the `file.in` file).

The `sed` expressions simple look for lines in `template.txt` that start with either `seed` or `output` and inserts the appropriate values.